# Primes representable as difference of two integer powers with different exponents

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

For example, $7$ can be represented as $7=2^4-3^2$. And $17$ as $17=7^2-2^5$.

Requirement that exponents be different is here because of $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$. Also, we want that exponents be $\geq 2$, to avoid trivialities.

Suppose also that in the representation $p=x^m-y^n$ we always have $x\neq 1,-1$ and $y \neq 1,-1$.

This could be known, and to be honest I did not search the web for an answer, but instead went directly to ask you:

> Can every prime be represented in this way?

Comment: It's not a prime, but according to OEIS [A053289](https://oeis.org/A053289) entry it is open whether 6 is a difference of two perfect powers. This may indicate the difficulty of the kind of problems we are dealing with here.

Comment: @Wojowu But in the question above powers need not be consecutive.

Comment: Neither they have to be in the question of whether 6 is a difference.

Comment: @Wojowu Right. So this is hard, I thought that maybe it´s not hard. As an amateur I do not know very much the current state-of-the-art.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be the set of integers which can **not** be a difference of the type you want. Then it would appear to be very hard to prove that a given (prime) number is in $S.$ But it is not hard to argue convincingly that many specific numbers are in $S$. This in turn is very strong evidence that "most" numbers are not of this form.

Probably all $24$ integers in

$\{6, 14, 21, \mathbf{29},  \mathbf{31}, 33, 34, 42,  \mathbf{43}, 50, 51, 52, 58,  \mathbf{59}, 62, 66, 69, 70, 75, 77, 78, 82, 84, 85\},$ 
including the $4$ prime members, are in $S.$ That is, none can be written as such a difference (everything else up to $83$ can). I'd bet that no-one can find two members of that set which are such a difference.

So my answer to your question (without a proof) would

> No, there are primes which can not be expressed as a difference of the type you seek. In fact most can't. However we can't produce any specific one that provably can't.

The main idea is that it is pretty rare to get a small difference from big powers so once we get the the very big powers most of the small differences we've not yet seen we won't see. The list above comes from examining differences $x^m-y^n$ with both $x^m$ and $y^n$ under $10^9.$

You pointed out that allowing a difference of squares gives all odd integers. However one could relax the condition to "not both squares" so allow things like $b^7-a^7.$ Of course only the case $b=a+1$ is useful for primes since $b-a$ is a factor. But, up to $10^9$ there are only $17$ perfect $7$th powers so allowing this would give $16$ differences.

There are some ambiguities in the conditions, though they don't really change the answer. For example, is $b^6-a^{10}$ forbidden since it is a difference of two squares or allowed because it is a $3$rd power minus a $5$th power? I'll call that forbidden.

Under $10^9$ there are $1047$ powers which are not squares and $3642$ squares.

First let me look at $x^m-y^n$ with both $m,n \geq 3.$ Only $73$ differences among them are under $1000.$ The last one is $26^3-7^5=769$ which uses the $29$th and $30$th members of that list.

Now let me look at the differences $|x^m-y^2|$ with $m \geq 3.$ Here I'll just look at differences up to $100.$ There are $132$ of them which, as it happens, give $66$ distinct values. The last new one is $568^3-13537^2=63.$ This uses member $601$ from that list of non-square powers. The previous new one is $56^3-419^2=55$ using member $62$ from the list of non-square powers. So members $63$ through $600$ and also $602$ through $1047$ give nothing new under $100$. If that list is extended further would it give anything else under $100?$ Maybe, but it defies the imagination that all $24$ members of the set I started with (as much as would fit on one line) would be obtained.

On the other hand, perhaps my imagination is too impoverished.

Comment: Question 283903 has a list of some differences of powers, and the observation that interesting examples involve an odd power. To enrich your imagination, compute only odd powers as well as the nearest or two nearest squares.  In particular, computing the first thousand fifth powers and their nearest cubes and nearest squares may yield a few more examples, even if they are primes above 100.  Gerhard "Look Where The Power Is" Paseman, 2017.12.18.